# .RefreshAll doesnt allow other processing

Tags: excel, vba

The following code, specifically the replace formula, works great until I un-remark the line containing the .refreshAll statement. The workbook refreshes as expected but the replace functionality now doesn't work. Is there some sort of command I need to issue to tell Excel to allow further processing?

NOTE: It looks like it actually replaces the characters appropriately but then immediately changes it back to the original text.

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    Dim q As Integer
    'ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    'turn off autofilter
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ShowAutoFilter = False
    For q = 1 To 18: Worksheets(1).Cells(2, q) = Replace(Worksheets(1).Cells(2, q), "_", " "): Next q
End Sub
```

Comment: `Is there some sort of command I need to issue to tell Excel to allow further processing` Have you tried `doevents`?

Comment: I have now :) I was hoping that was it even though its something easy that I should have thought to try. No luck. Same results.

Comment: Hmm maybe set refresh to false afterwards then do the replace? Or even save it first then replace? Not sure XD

Comment: I figured it out.... Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry I was typing but forgot I cant hit enter in this box... By default, Excel sets "Enable background refresh". When I turn this off it allows the refresh to finish before continuing with the rest of the processing. Thanks again!!!